# Is nwjs fast enough for a media manager application?

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I'm planning on writting an application which would be a kind of media manager for videos and images (for organising in playlists and galleries, and displaying it inside the app), it will involve a lot of drag and drop and db access, will building this app with lots of javascript and nwjs be fast enough for that kind of app? or should I switch to c++/qt or something like that?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to give you an exact answer because you did not specifiy the architecture.

From my experience I can tell you that acces to the database und javascript in combination are fast enough to build a videomanager. You should consinder a smart concept behind the actual ressources. I would not load any content into a db as a blob or so. Your should only save the relative links to files in a directory.

You have multiple example of nwjs apps that are doing something similar. For example [Atraci](https://github.com/Atraci/Atraci) or [Powder Player](https://github.com/jaruba/PowderPlayer)

You should try a building a simple App where you load a video and an mp3 from a file. If it is fast enough for you, than you can expect that I will not be problem building some javascript and db accesses arround it. It would say it is totally possible.

Download node-webkit. Install [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) and try to move a file to a folder and save the link. Call the link on the next page and you will see.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer :) yes I have in mind to embed an sqlite3 db with path of the medias. In terms of architecture I don't fully understand what you mean, it would be a pure desktop app without server requests, is that what you are reffering to? if not can you please list some that would be good for my app?

Comment: But, on the other hand, I was thinking about using the node part of the webkit to have my app to build a server on the machine on which it is running to process the requests of the view part, but I don't know if it is a good idea or a very stupid one (yes I am a newbie in web applications and client-server architecture :)

Comment: You can build pure desktop apps with node-webkit than run on windows, mac an linux. If you need to access a server later you are already working with webtechnologies and can access it. You try it and then you will see. Without a try you will not find out.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is !

Popcorntime.io, a very popular video streaming application (using HTML5 video player AND bittorrent client & rich interface) was build using node-webkit.

Spotify is also using a rich GUI and is "kindof" nw based.